# Vim Regex for html

Tags: regex, vim

Working with vim regexes for folding html, trying to ignore html tags that start and end on the same line.

So far, I have

```
if line =~# '<\(\w\+\).*<\/\1>'
  return '='
endif
```

Which works fine for tags like `<a></a>`, but when dealing with custom elements, I run into issues since there is a hyphen in the tag name.

Like for example, this element

```
<paper-input label="Input label"></paper-input>
```

What needs to change in the regex to also catch the hyphen?

Comment: What exactly you are trying to match here? This doesn't sound clear to me.

Comment: Apologies, maybe a gist would help. https://gist.github.com/mhartington/96c226aba980513489a9a6fa1d085ecf

The regex should match the tags that starts and ends on the sample line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct regex (updated because of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39380964/vim-sed-regex-backreference-in-search-pattern)) is:

```
<\([^ >]\+\)[ >].*<\/\1>
```

or

```
<\([^ >]\+\)\>.*<\/\1>
```

This is important `[^ >]`. This will match any character until `whitespace` or `>` i.e. it will match both `a` and `paper_input`

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! Interesting, thanks for the info!

Comment: @mhartington To be honest I have never used backreference in search pattern. It seems to work but I'm not sure if this is the correct way.

Comment: @mhartington I was analyzing it further and asked a question regarding backreference: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39380964/vim-sed-regex-backreference-in-search-pattern). This version: `<([^ >]+)[ >].*<\/\1>` will be safer.