# Vim / sed regex backreference in search pattern

Tags: regex, vim, sed, backreference, capturing-group

Vim help says that:

> ```
> \1      Matches the same string that was matched by     */\1* *E65*
>         the first sub-expression in \( and \). {not in Vi}
>         Example: "\([a-z]\).\1" matches "ata", "ehe", "tot", etc.
> ```

It looks like the *backreference* can be used in search pattern. I started playing with it and I noticed behavior that I can't explain. This is my file:

```
<paper-input label="Input label"> Some text </paper-input>
<paper-input label="Input label"> Some text </paper-inputa>
<aza> Some text </az>
<az> Some text </az>
<az> Some text </aza>
```

I wanted to match the lines where the opening and closing tags are matching i.e.:

```
<paper-input label="Input label"> Some text </paper-input>
<az> Some text </az>
```

And my test regex is:

```
%s,<\([^ >]\+\).*<\/\1>,,gn
```

But this matches lines: `1`, `3` and `4`. Same thing with **sed**:

```
$ sed -ne 's,<\([^ >]\+\).*<\/\1>,\0,p' file
<paper-input label="Input label"> Some text </paper-input>
<aza> Some text </az>
<az> Some text </az>
```

This: `<\([^ >]\+\)` should be greedy and when trying to match it without `\1` at the end then all the groups are correct. But when I add `\1` it seems that `<\([^ >]\+\)` becomes not greedy and it tries to force the match in *3rd line*. Can someone explain why it matches `3rd` line:

```
<aza> Some text </az>
```

This is also a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/nT4fP6/1)

**NOTE**
This is not about the regex itself (probably there is other way to do it) but about the behavior of that regex.

Comment: You should take a look at backtracking engines. If it doesn't find a match the engine backtracks until and chooses something different. For instance `\1` equals `az` on line three after all of the backtracking. (Since you never added anchors)

Comment: to add to @FDinoff's point, you can add a rule to match a space or > as anchors... `<\([^ >]\+\)[ >].*<\/\1>`

Comment: @FDinoff This is intresting. I didn't know about it.

Comment: @spasic Yes, I understood how backtracking works and the anchors for space and > seem to be the best idea here.

Comment: @FDinoff If you add this as an answer I will mark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand why your regex behaves the way it does you need to understand what a backtracking regex engine does.

The engine will greedily match and consume as many characters as it can. But if it doesn't find a match it goes back and tries to find a different match that still satisfies the pattern.

```
%s,<\([^ >]\+\).*<\/\1>,,gn
```

For line three `<aza> Some text </az>`,

The regex engine looks at `\1 = aza`. and sees if `.*</aza>` matches the rest of the string. It doesn't so it chooses something else for `\1`. The next time it chooses `\1 = az` and sees if `.*</az>` matches the rest of the string and it does. So the string matches

(This is a simplified version. I skipped over the fact that `.*` can potentially do a lot of backtracking itself)

---

Solving it is as easy as adding an anchor in the regex stops the regex from searching for other values that could satisfy `\1`. In this case matching a space or `>` is sufficient.

Comment: This is very good explanation.  Ending word with `\>` i.e. `<\([^ >]\+\)\>.*</\1>` as suggested by @LucHermitte will also work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `\>` to indicate *end of word*. There may be other solutions with 0-width patterns, but it'll complicates things.

Also, your separator is `,`, not `/`

Which gives:

```
%s,<\([^ >]\+\)\>.*</\1>,,gn
```

Comment: This won't match 1st line. Besides, as I mentioned in the question - I want to understand why my regex is not working.

Comment: I've just checked. This does match first line (I've just checked my gvim 7.4-2207, and vim 7-4-2181 I have at hand). Regex 101 doesn't handle it well though.
Regarding the explanation, @FDinoff already gave it.

Comment: @DawidGrabowski,
This works as expected with vim 7.3-429 as well. Could it be that you've altered `&isk` definition?

Comment: Instead of copying the regex I did write it and make a mistake. It's working (sed and vim)

Comment: That happens :)

Answer (score 0):

Currently the reason why line 3 (`<aza>`) is showing up as a match is that the `.*` term in your regex can match across multiple lines.  So line 3 matches because line 5 has the closing tag.  To correct this, force the regex to find a matching closing tag on the *same* line only:

```
%s,<\([^ >]\+\)[^\n]*?<\/\1>,,gn
               ^^^^^ use [^\n]* instead of .*
```

Comment: Why do you think `.*` is matching accross multiples lines? It matches any character **except** new line

Comment: @DawidGrabowski Then how do you explain line 3 is showing up as a match?

Comment: I don't know. This is why I asked this question. I know that `.*` is definitely not matching new line. I added [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/nT4fP6/1).

Comment: `\_.` can match a newline with vim. not `.`